# Programaticly dismiss popover in SwifUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, popover, nspopover

I try to dismiss a popover with setting the variable, that shows it to false.

The sample code behaves quite strange.
Is there a better way to dismiss the popover programaticly with the Cancel Button?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  let lines = ["line 1", "line 2","line 3"]
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(lines, id: \.self)
      { Line(text: $0)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct Line: View {
  @State var text: String
  @State var showSheet = false

  var body: some View {
    VStack
    { Text("\(text)")
      .onTapGesture {
        self.showSheet = true
      }
    }.popover( isPresented: self.$showSheet,
               arrowEdge: .trailing
             )
    { Pop(showSheet: self.$showSheet)
    }
  }
}

struct Pop: View {
  @Binding var showSheet: Bool

  var body: some View {
    VStack {   
      Text("Option 1")
      Text("Option 2")
      Button("Cancel")
      { self.showSheet = false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I run the sample code in Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504) in the iPhone 11 simulator. There it's not possible to klick and dismiss multiple timees. On the Device it runs fine - maybe a simulator problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not clear from question in which environment and what exactly *strange* happens, because as tested the provided code works well with Xcode 11.2/3+ and iOS13.2+.

Anyway there is alternate approach to close popovers using `\.presentationMode` as below

**Update:** Well, I've found that original question probably concerns about `macOS`, because provided on macOS popover is not closed with described scenario.

Here is a variant of usage for both iOS/macOS platforms (tested & works with Xcode 11.3 / macOS 10.15)

```
struct Pop: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool
    //@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Option 1")
            Text("Option 2")
            Button("Cancel")
            {
                #if os(OSX)
                NSApp.sendAction(#selector(NSPopover.performClose(_:)), to: nil, from: nil)
                #else
                //self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // << behaves the same as below
                self.showSheet = false
                #endif
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx - any idea, how to reduce the size of the popup in iOS - it's always almost fullscreen

Comment: The root cause for my problem was a different one: I described it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152674/swiftui-popup-does-not-dismiss